# Grid rendering in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, grids-graticules

Rendering a grid in QGIS causes problems: The outmost grid line is not drawn on different zoom-levels:

Here it is ok:

[image]

While here it is not ok:

[image]

I have tried to change these rendering-settings, but had no luck:

[image]

Comment: Is this a question or a bug report? Bug reports are off-topic; they belong on the software-specific bug reporting site (in this case issues.qgis.org).

Comment: its a question: howto workaround this problem

Comment: It looks like the lines that disappear are on the edge of the CRS extent. At some zoom levels they fall outside the CRS extent, and thus aren't rendered. If you move them in slightly, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a known behavior of projection rendering in the software. Because meridians 180W and 180E represent the same meridian on the spheroid, most software clip this edge to avoid incorrect rendering or present both on one side. I think the same behavior you can find in ArcMap.

For this particular projection, you can manually add both meridians at 180 degrees. If this does not work, try using 179.999999 degrees. I hope this helps.

You can also add ocean layer and you will see where is the edge of the projection in the software.